# HTML placeholder attribute is not a valid attribute

Tags: html, sharepoint-2010, placeholder, applicationpage

On SharePoint application page
I am using placeholder in `<input>` like this:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="your name" />
```

But placeholder is underlined and says: Validation (XHTML 1.0 transitional) Attribute placeholder is not a valid attribute. But when i put `runat = "server"`, error goes away

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="your name" runat="server" />
```

Now, its valid attribute. I could not understand why placeholder attribute is not valid without `runat = "server"`. Can anybody tell the reason? I did not want to use `runat = "server"`.

I have also added `<!DOCTYPE html>`at top of the application page, but still it gives same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using HTML5 markup, with XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype

placeholder, article, footer, etc are all HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Above is the appropriate DOCTYPE for HTML5.

Comment: I am actually using SharePoint application page where i placed <asp:content>. Inside <asp:contant>, i am using <form> and <input type=text name="name" placeholder="your name"> I have put <!DOCTYPE html> Before <asp:content> tag, but still placeholder attribute is not valid and is underlined. any idea ?

Comment: no, i have no idea about asp.net, you added html5 as a question tag so that's why i was able to add answer :D but still i can search for you

Answer (score 0):

placeholder is a HTML5 attribute, Therefore it *shouldn't* be valid under xHTML 1.0 Transitional. As for the `runat` attribute changing the behavior, it's most likely a flaw in the system or just being suppressed for some reason.